# onEdit trigger to send email in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am limited in my abilities so please be patient with me.  I have the following task.  My first tab has a log of student names, time stamps, and locations.  I have written a script that triggers an onEdit email when the last column has “Guidance Counselor” typed in.  I am trying to alter the script so that the following task can occur.  I want an onEdit email to be triggered when a specific student’s name is entered into column 1.  However, I do not want to enter the script each time and type the list of student names that I want/need an email to be triggered for.  My thought process is that I want to be able to have a separate tab with a list of names that I can update on a regular basis and when a cell value in column 1 matches a name that is in the other tab it triggers an email on that edit.
Here is the url for my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JiZXEtB3-B0C10TEy2CIFjdckhH3THNZaVo7lVsIg9k/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code for my script so far that triggers an email on “Guidance Counselor”  I know its not that clean.

```
function emailonEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 

  // EVENT VARIABLES 
  let range = e.range; 
  let row = e.range.getRow(); 
  let col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); 

  let studentName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); 
  let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7j1qB6JJ3q6IzGn8eL1R4-hJs8-GqMXlu9NpiakUts/edit#gid=0"

  if ( col == 6 && cellValue == "Guidance Counselor") {
    // Browser.msgBox('It works'); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'fayj@bathwildcats.org',
      studentName + ' enroute to GUIDANCE!',
      url + '&range=' + cellLocation
    ); 
  }

     if ( col == 6 && cellValue == "Guidance Counselor") {
    // Browser.msgBox('It works'); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'jimfay55@icloud.com',
      studentName + ' enroute to GUIDANCE!',
      url + '&range=' + cellLocation
    ); 
  }; 

  if ( col == 6 && cellValue == "Guidance Counselor") {
    // Browser.msgBox('It works'); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'NavianceStudent2022@gmail.com',
      studentName + ' enroute to GUIDANCE!',
      url + '&range=' + cellLocation
    ); 
  }; 
 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function emailonEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  const lsh = e.source.getSheetByName("student name list");
  const list = lsh.getRange(2,1,lsh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let studentName = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue(); 
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  let cellLocation = e.range.getA1Notation(); 
  let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7j1qB6JJ3q6IzGn8eL1R4-hJs8-GqMXlu9NpiakUts/edit#gid=0"
  if ( e.range.columnStart == 6 && ~list.indexOf(studentName) && e.value == "Guidance Counselor") {
    MailApp.sendEmail('fayj@bathwildcats.org,NavianceStudent2022@gmail.com,jimfay55@icloud.com',studentName + ' enroute to GUIDANCE!',url + '&range=' + cellLocation ); 
  } 
}
```

- [bitwise not(~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: thanks for the work @Cooper I am able to get this to trigger my email when column 6 says "Guidance Counselor" but I cannot get it to trigger an email when column 1 has Student A entered and column 6 says "office".

Comment: If we separate the guidance counselor trigger out and dont even worry about that as I think I can make that work independently.  How can I get the script to trigger an email when a student name in Column 1 matches one of the names in a separate tab?

Comment: Did  you change the name of the sheet were the list is?  I have "student name list" as it's name now.

Comment: Yeah what is weird about that is I tried using the tab name of my list and I kept getting an appscript email error that said "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null, so I changed that sheet name to my initial log tab name and it sent the emails for "guidance counselor" but would not do anything else.

Comment: I hope that you realize that this is not the kind of function you can call from the script editor or even a menu.  It has to be call be an onEdit trigger that provides the event object.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative Answer

First, you may convert the student list from 2 dimensional into 1 dimensional by using `.toString()` and `.split()` functions. Afterwards, you can use the `.includes()` function to check if the student name is included in your list.

```
function emailonEdit(e) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7j1qB6JJ3q6IzGn8eL1R4-hJs8-GqMXlu9NpiakUts/edit#gid=0";
  var cellLocation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var dataRange = e.range;
  var dataColumn = dataRange.getColumn();
  var dataRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var studentName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log").getRange(dataRow,1).getValue();
  var studentListSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
  var studentList = studentListSheet.getRange(2,1,studentListSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var checkName = studentList.toString().split(",").includes(studentName); /**returns true if the student name is included in the List*/
  (dataColumn == 6 && checkName && e.value == "Guidance Counselor") ? MailApp.sendEmail("fayj@bathwildcats.org, jimfay55@icloud.com, NavianceStudent2022@gmail.com", studentName + ' enroute to GUIDANCE!', url + '&range=' + cellLocation) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("sending failed");
}
```

I also added a `toast()` function to send a popup notification if the conditions of the trigger were not met.

References:

- [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)
- [toString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)
- [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)
- [toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.